# Images from imgur fail over ssl

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, imgur

When loading TeX.SX over TLS (e.g. [Force equal hinting when combining symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275175/force-equal-hinting-when-combining-symbols)) with *HTTPS Everywhere*, images are not displayed.

Firefox shows this error (e.g. for https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1rDN.png):

> An error occurred during a connection to i.stack.imgur.com. Peer
>   reports it experienced an internal error. (Error code:
>   ssl_error_internal_error_alert)

Comment: Can you please hit this URL and paste the result? Your specific IP isn't necessary, you can remove that piece. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdn-cgi/trace

Comment: Is this what is causing all SE hosted avatars to fail to load in chat?

Comment: @NickCraver All of i.stack.imgur.com is returning: "i.stack.imgur.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for ssl330558.cloudflaressl.com (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)"

Comment: Certificate presented doesn't belong to `i.stack.imgur.com` (issued only to `ssl330558.cloudflaressl.com`, no alternate names) and both image URLs and that `trace` thing result in 403.

Comment: You can try with http only, @Mysticial

Comment: @NickCraver: With http (https gives a 403): `fl=48f8
h=i.stack.imgur.com
ts=1446070144.771
visit_scheme=http
uag=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
colo=DUS
spdy=off
loc=DE`

Comment: @Oded my school appears to disallow imgur.com simply because of the lack of TSL (or similar). Is this fixable by you? / is it an unrelated problem?

Comment: @NickCraver I get similar - `fl=21f130
h=i.stack.imgur.com
ts=1446070560.828
visit_scheme=https
uag=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
colo=LHR
spdy=3.1
loc=GB` And can see the image he linked...

Comment: @Tim - if they block imgur.com (note that we are on a *subdomain* i.stack.imgur.com), that is not something we can help with :(

Comment: Hmm when I'm back there in a week I'll speak to them. I seem to remember a TLS error (???) but not sure. This seems like an unrelated problem tho i guess.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Is this fixed for you? It's all fine for me... And has been for the whole day.

Comment: Oh, so *that's* why some images have trouble displaying suddenly. I'm not even browsing via HTTPS...

Comment: @NickCraver broken for me as well (over HTTP): `fl=63f12
h=i.stack.imgur.com
ts=1446071939.274
visit_scheme=http
uag=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2547.0 Safari/537.36
colo=MAN
spdy=off
loc=GB`

Comment: @NickCraver I get a certificate error with that: http://i.imgur.com/wjWAiec.png. Looks like an issue with Cloudflare again. Man, SE's had *so many* problems with them lately..

Comment: Thanks for the reports everyone - we're prodding CloudFlare who's in front of `i.stack.imgur.com` and has incorrect certificates in some colos. It's not directly our account, but hosted in behalf of imgur *for* us so resolving takes a bit more time. We'll get them to correct the cert issue ASAP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a certificate fail on the CloudFlare side on the Imgur account hosted on our behalf. We're still awaiting info on what exactly happened, but since it's not directly our account we may not get this information.

The fix should be rolling out shortly around the world - we prodded both sides to have new certs issues ASAP and we are now seeing valid certificates in most locations (our New York sysamins aren't seeing it yet).

> **New cert details**
>
> - Valid From: Tuesday, October 27, 2015 at 8:00:00 PM EDT
> - Valid To: Thursday, October 27, 2016 at 7:59:59 PM EDT
> - SHA1: `96 BD DF 71 49 F8 C6 D9 A8 6E 2D E1 D3 5D 2F 00 6A 90 0C ED`
> - MD5: `90 13 A3 FD B5 61 F4 B5 E9 8D DC 8B D7 9D BE C5`
> - SAN entries:
>
>   - `i.stack.imgur.com`
>   - `imgur.cloudflaressl.com`

Comment: See you all again next year guys!