# SE sites styling messed up

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design, stack-exchange

I have tried refreshing and everything, but I still can't get rid of this so am starting to think that this is server-side rather than me (and many others are saying that hey have it too):

[image]

And it is not just the chat rooms, the whole SE chat site is messed up...:

[image]

I am running Firefox 41 on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10.

**Information Update:**

I am also noticing similar problems on this site (where I am posting this question).

Comment: Can you hit this url: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cdn-cgi/trace and paste the results? (no need for your specific IP - you can delete that)

Comment: @Mysticial: I am getting the same issue with the HTTP versions of the sites.

Comment: Likely to be the same issue (the avatars are likely fetched over https)

Comment: @oded: I get a notice saying that I can't continue due to it being an insecure connection... And that it can't verify the identity of the site.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda - are you using https everywhere? Try with http only.

Comment: @oded: Yes, but I have tried http.

Comment: https everywhere forces https - you need to disable it first.

Comment: FWIW same here.

Comment: Same resolution as described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268605/140505